# 3d camera calibration using opencv

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm working on the calibration of a camera using opencv, I run the given sample project, my question is how to set the  metric system in the input data for ex.:

```
  <!-- The size of a square in some user defined metric system (pixel, millimeter)-->
    <Square_Size>(1,10)</Square_Size>
```

does it mean  that every pixel represent 10um ? 
thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use the classic checkerboard for calibration, square size is the actual physical size of a square in that board. For example, if it is 10cm, you should put `<Square_Size>10</Square_Size>`. Alternatively, you could express it in inches and put `<Square_Size>3.937</Square_Size>`. This is the units that it refers to. The size is used by OpenCV to create the model coordinates and the units do not affect your resultant calibration parameters.